# Replacing blank elements in list of pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Question edited for clarity:

I have a column in a pandas dataframe where each element is a list

```
Index      X
  1     ['1','2','3']
  2     ['4','5','6']
  3     ['']
```

I want it to look like the following:

```
Index      X
  1     ['1','2','3']
  2     ['4','5','6']
  3     ['0']
```

Comment: `df.fillna(0)` something like this

Comment: The elements aren't 'nan' they are just blanks

Comment: `df.replace("",0)` then I guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your column is object type, something like this should work:

```
# Example of dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'col_1': [1,2,3], 'col_2' : [[1,2,3,4],[''],['']]})
col_1   col_2
0   1   [1, 2, 3, 4]
1   2   []
2   3   []
```

Using pandas.apply should do the trick for you

```
df["col_2"].apply(lambda x : ['0'] if x==[''] else x)
```

Answer (score 2):

not an answer but:

in your df, I have a hard time to `df.iat[0, 0]=['']` or `df.iat[0, 0]=[]`
pandas really discourages you from using a list inside a df cell.

Comment: The column is not a list I understand the difference. Each element in the column contains a list and some of these lists happen to be blank.

Comment: if you can guarantee all of elements is a list then: `df.loc[len(df['X'])==0, 'X'] = 0` is to replace the list with 0, if you want to **fill** the list to be `[0]`, that's another question

Comment: There are several instances where an element will simply be a list that us [''']. I want to turn these lists into [0].

Comment: I think some of us needs to go in and edit your question again... it was not crystal clear

Comment: Edited for clarity

Answer (score 2):

Use nested list comprehension for replace '' in lists to `0`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'X':[[''], ['a',''], []]})

df['X'] = [[0 if y =='' else y for y in x] for x in df['X']]
print (df)
        X
0     [0]
1  [a, 0]
2      []
```

Comment: For the first solution i get " 'int' object has no attribute 'loc' " and for the second solution I get " 'int' object is not subscriptable"

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replace only `' '` try:

```
df.loc[df['X']=='', 'X'] = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this peace of code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"X":[["a"], ["b"], [""], []]})
df.head()

    X
0   [a]
1   [b]
2   []
3   []

def replace_empty(X):
    for n, i in enumerate(X):
        if i == '':
            X[n] = 0
    return X

df.X = df.X.apply(lambda x: replace_empty(x))
df.head()

    X
0   [a]
1   [b]
2   [0]
3   []
```